# Rake and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, rake

I am a new user on RoR. I would really appreciate it if you can give me some guidance here. Below is the issue that I have encountered. Thank you in advance!

I am trying to do the following command

> C:\Users\01TAN\rails_projects\demo_app>bundle exec rake db:migrate

However, I received the following error

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
undefined method `vantan08' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinit
ion:0x217c128>
```

I used the trace command and below is the report:

```
C:\Users\01TAN\rails_projects\demo_app>rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `vantan08' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinit
ion:0x2378430>
C:/Users/01TAN/rails_projects/demo_app/db/migrate/20120325153442_create_users.rb
:4:in `block in change'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table
'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:450:in `block in method_missing'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:424:in `block in say_with_time'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:424:in `say_with_time'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:444:in `method_missing'
C:/Users/01TAN/rails_projects/demo_app/db/migrate/20120325153442_create_users.rb
:3:in `change'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:393:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:393:in `block in migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:118:in `with_connectio
n'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:377:in `migrate'
C:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:704:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:759:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:759:in `block in ddl_transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:190:in `transactio
n'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:759:in `ddl_transaction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:703:in `block in migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:684:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:684:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:554:in `up'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:535:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:153:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:205:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:200:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:200:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.
rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/appli
cation.rb:63:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
 `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: The code of the migration would be more useful than the last 90% of the trace...

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. I just found out the answer already.

Comment: @user1291439: Then please either delete the question or post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the migration you were writing mixed up the name of a column with the type of a column. Migrations should look something like this in Rails 3.2.1:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```